# Temporarily stop everyone from accessing mysql DB

Tags: mysql, php, httpd

I am going to migrate a LAMP server tonight, it uses php and mysql with apache on centos.  I want to stop people from accessing the site/database while I back it up.  Will stopping httpd be a sufficient way to stop people from accessing the DB, and will I be able to do mysqldump during this time?  There are no other DB connectors that connect to this mysql other than the php running as an apache mod.

Answer (score 2):

Just issue a:

```
mysql> FLUSH TABLES WITH READ LOCK;
```

Then back up your database.

Comment: But be careful, as `FLUSH TABLES WITH READ LOCK;` can cause problems and even downtime. Just check it afterwards and resolve any problems. See http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/2012/03/23/how-flush-tables-with-read-lock-works-with-innodb-tables/

Comment: @StefanLasiewski - excellent point.